# compile failing - Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml

Tags: java, maven, gradle, compilation

Literally just hit up key in my command line to get the last command to compile my java project. Is this a combination of `updatePolicy` and a server error on RedHat side?

I'm not behind a proxy or anything, did not change anything.

`Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.`

> Could not resolve javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.+.
>     Required by:
>         project :
>   Failed to list versions for javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error

If this is an issue with RedHat though, I should be seeing more issues streaming in but I don't so it makes me believe it's an issue on my side but can't think of anything on my side.

edit 1: in my `build.gradle` I can see 
   `maven {
        url "https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/"
    }`

can this be changed to an address that is not failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an issue on Redhat maven repository side, the server seems down: if you try to download manually some artefacts you also get 500 errors:  e.g. : https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/javax/

You can add other repositories in your `repositories` block :

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()

}
```

These two repositories should allow you to resolve all "standard" libraries in RELEASE version. You did not specify in your question which version of the servlet-api you need, but it should be there.

**EDIT** see https://access.redhat.com/articles/3620281 that can explain service down

Comment: yes, I already had them added, I just deleted the entry for redhat and it worked. thanks.